# Switching the receiver and the argument of `Enumerable#inject`

Tags: ruby, enumerable

When `Enumerable#inject` is used, most of the times, we want the result to be the same class (and often the same object) as the initial object that appears as the argument of `inject`. For example, we use it like:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
.inject(5){|i, e| i += e}
# => 20

[3, 4, 5]
.inject(1 => 1, 2 => 1){|h, e| h[e] = h[e - 1] + h[e - 2]; h}
# => {1=>1, 2=>1, 3=>2, 4=>3, 5=>5}
```

From the point of view that this operation takes the initial value and modifies it into the final output, it would be more natural to have the initial value as the receiver and write like this:

```
5
.foo([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]){|i, e| i += e}
# => 20

{1 => 1, 2 => 1}
.foo([3, 4, 5]){|h, e| h[e] = h[e - 1] + h[e - 2]; h}
# => {1=>1, 2=>1, 3=>2, 4=>3, 5=>5}
```

where `Object#foo` would be defined as

```
def foo enum, &pr; enum.inject(self, &pr) end
```

Is there a ready-made method in some library that resembles this `foo`?

Comment: `resembles this foo?` means?

Comment: Do you have a real example of what you're trying to do? Something that will replace the `...` with real code.

Comment: I imagine that the reason no one has made such a library method (to my knowledge) is that it forces every single Ruby object to know about Enumerable#inject.  That's a pretty high price to pay just to get this syntax... which IMHO is worse than the original syntax for inject, because it lacks the advantage of being able to write fluent map-reduce operations by "daisy-chaining" the #map and #inject operations.

Comment: @charleyc Your comment may make sense to some people but does not to me who is asking whether there is such library whereas your sentence is interpretable only under the presupposition that there is no such library.

Comment: Yes, I am explaining why I expect that no such library exists.  I can't prove that one doesn't exist.

Comment: @charleyc Regarding convenience, you are not considering the oppposite case where you may want to chain the initial value.