# What is a mnemonic for remembering how to call ruby inject?

Tags: ruby

I can never remember if its

```
array.inject{|memo,obj| block}
```

or

```
array.inject{|obj,memo| block}
```

Does anyone have a good trick for remembering the order?

Comment: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject ?

Comment: This is also the idea that motivated [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16123680/switching-the-receiver-and-the-argument-of-enumerableinject).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`inject`/`reduce` is nothing but a [left fold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_%28higher-order_function%29) (thus called `foldl`/`foldLeft` in other languages), that's it, the recursive **left-associative** combination of elements with a binary operator:

```
(1..5).reduce(:+) == (((1 + 2) + 3) + 4) + 5 #=> true
(1..5).reduce(:-) == (((1 - 2) - 3) - 4) - 5 #=> true
```

So it's only natural that the accumulator is passed as the left/first argument of the block. On a right fold the accumulator would be the right/second argument.

Not really a mnemonic, but once you realize that `reduce` is a left fold, you won't forget where the accumulator goes.

Answer (score 2):

It is the reverse of `each_with_object`, which I do manage to remember (first the `each`, then the `object`).

Answer (score 1):

If you actually think of it manipulating a `memo` and an `object` then it's alphabetical:

```
array.inject{|memo,obj| block}
```

Your mnemonic is that memo comes before object alphabetically.

Answer (score 0):

> **When using inject with short blocks, name the arguments |a, e|
>     (mnemonic: accumulator, element)**

or

> **not good, but it helps me: "memo" comes first (alphabetically), so it is
>   inject(memo, obj)**

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].inject([]) do |result, elm|
  result << elm * 2 if elm % 2 == 0
  result
end
# => [4, 8, 12]
```

> So what is this doing? Inject in english is:
>
> Start with some object (our empty array) and then pass each element in our caller ([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]) to the block. Provide a result object that the block can freely change. The result starts out as our first parameter (the empty array) and then becomes whatever the block evaluates last.

Further details [`Here`](http://www.potstuck.com/2011/07/25/map-if-in-ruby-and-an-introduction-to-rubys-inject/)